# Can I use z-score for data that doesn't belong to a normal distribution but passes some normality tests?

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, z-score

I've done an experiment with several essays in humans, and I have the mean and variance of the results of all essays per human (each data point is not independent from each other because of the nature of the metric I'm using).

I'm creating a model that predicts human behavior, and I want to know how well it is performing. So I thought about computing the mean and variance of all means and compute how many standard deviations away is my model from the mean of means. Does this make sense? The data passed z-test from MATLAB. If it doesn't, what other kind of measure of dispersion could I use?

Mean for each human for four different categories of essays:

`[[0.5450  0.6605  1.0846  1.2752];
[0.5704  0.7386  0.9530  1.0476];
[0.5307  0.7269  0.7603  0.8317];
[0.5673  0.6713  1.0126  1.1333];
[0.4641  0.5162  0.7868  0.8933];
[0.4872  0.5299  0.8521  0.9655];
[0.4610  0.5477  0.6610  0.7872];
[0.5682  0.6332  0.9416  1.3915];
[0.4832  0.4663  0.7870  0.9705];
[0.4965  0.4920  0.8236  0.8065];
[0.4576  0.5171  0.7066  0.7857];
[0.4797  0.5849  0.9257  0.9133];
[0.5316  0.7297  1.1286  1.0829];
[0.4475  0.5560  0.8381  0.3333];
[0.4863  0.5645  0.8010  1.0333];
[0.5326  0.6206  1.0022  0.9667];
[0.5063  0.6971  1.0398  1.0000];
[0.4620  0.4976  0.8451  1.5333];
[0.4559  0.5456  0.6881  1.5952];
[0.4449  0.4666  1.0014  0.6667];
[0.5060  0.5841  0.9442  NaN   ];
[0.5210  0.6592  0.9338  0.9167];
[0.5355  0.5837  0.7764  0.8095];
[0.5158  0.5478  0.9157  0.8333]]`

Standard deviation for each human for four different categories of essays:

`[[0.3231  0.5578  0.8506  1.4848];
[0.3297  0.5541  0.5780  1.3469];
[0.2867  0.5482  0.5948  0.7591];
[0.3661  0.5505  0.5888  0.7310];
[0.2216  0.3942  0.7027  0.7470];
[0.2497  0.4051  0.6257  0.9586];
[0.2481  0.4105  0.4684  0.4857];
[0.3348  0.4401  0.5719  1.8024];
[0.2916  0.3877  0.5794  0.5054];
[0.3020  0.3879  0.5681  0.6255];
[0.2452  0.4009  0.5164  0.5190];
[0.2612  0.4558  0.7113  1.1915];
[0.2393  0.4104  0.6467  0.9595];
[0.2475  0.3992  0.8032  0.5774];
[0.2684  0.4371  0.6703  0.7394];
[0.2363  0.4004  0.5972  1.0435];
[0.2091  0.3677  0.7398  0     ];
[0.2793  0.3872  0.3672  0.6600];
[0.2348  0.4044  0.5832  0.5724];
[0.2297  0.3957  0.5663  0.8819];
[0.2312  0.3826  0.4504  NaN   ];
[0.2219  0.4414  0.7050  1.1902];
[0.2791  0.4194  0.5304  0.7902];
[0.2901  0.4270  0.5227  0.3333]]`

Thanks in advance!